# Cannot get card responsive to mobile devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

please check this url.... http://rdarby.epizy.com/?i=1

It looks fine full size and responds well when the browser window is resized, however when I view this site from a mobile device or the chrome device emulator, both the bootstrap card and the modal pop up appear absolutely tiny.

I cannot find the cause of this and cannot see why it behaves differently on a resized browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the responsive meta tag?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the html header.

With it the browser should render the width of the page at the width of its own screen. So, when it's set, if that screen is 320px wide, the browser window will be 320px wide, rather than way zoomed out and showing 960px (or whatever that device does by default, in lieu of a responsive meta tag).

Comment: how could I miss something so obvious - thanks very much! will accept as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a viewport meta in the `head` of your html file:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  ...
```